# Don't calculate accepted answer rate on meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accept-rate

Meta is a discussion site and accepting an answer on many questions makes no sense.  Since this statistic is now reported, it may be taken as a measure of the level of participation.  For a discussion site, this stat makes much less sense, especially as a measure of participation.  I suggest that it not be calculated or reported for meta.

Comment: Why should we bother answering this, you only have a 29% acceptance rate :)

Comment: @John Rasch: don't.  :-)

Comment: Since [it's not shown anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951), you'll never see it, so even if it is calculated, it's worthless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look through my posts on here earlier -- most of those that haven't had an answer accepted are for things where there isn't a solution yet, or none of the answers (suggestions, even) match the actually implemented solution.

Answer (score 4):

I say go ahead and report it, but understand the nature of the site when you are looking at it.

Comment: I                 agree.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense *sometimes*, on support questions especially.

Since questions on meta require special tags, perhaps questions tagged with things like `feature-request` could be removed from the count.

Answer (score 1):

(I don't know why I bother answering this, there is only a one in 3 chance you will accept this :p)

I think it does make sense.

- Jeff can always select a different accepted answer
- You can select the "answer" you found most helpful, or that most comprehensively addressed your query.

There is no question that this feature increases participation, I cleaned up all my questions on Meta and SO recently, accepting feature requests I made on meta etc. If Jeff sees a feature request that is accepted that he is going to decline, he now is kind of forced to adding a reason and marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I just had someone say they would not have answered by question on Meta if they had saw my accept rate first.  So this is a real problem, as most questions on meta does not have one best answer.

Maybe only include questions tagged “support-request” when working out the “accept rate”

Comment: That "someone" was random and he was making fun of you. Don't whine!

Comment: Wasn't entirely *that* random, shamone!

Answer (score 0):

Please don't. It's the only site I have a 100% accept rate.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of SO functionality wasn't designed for Meta.SO but I would like to see ***as much* of the functionality maintained as possible** even where it might not be needed... for a few reasons:

- Meta.SO is a good place to try out functionality you might not want to try on a "professional" site.
- Stack Exchange is coming up and there is a lot to be learned seeing how SO features hold up under a site for which is was not specifically design (like meta.SO).
- I would like to see how the SO engine handles more traditional discussion needs of meta.SO.
- It would be useful to see to see how different features "work" in different types of community environments. The group dynamics *here* are certainly different than that of SO and the other sites.

Meta.SO is a bit experimental. I'm sure the SO team stands to learn a lot by maintaining meta.SO as a close macrocosm of the Stack Overflow proper.