# Stop displaying the accept rate on MSO

Tags: feature-request, meta, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't calculate accepted answer rate on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17055/dont-calculate-accepted-answer-rate-on-meta)

Given that the whole notion of asking/accepting questions is very different here on MSO and on meta sites in general, is it appropriate to display accept rate here?  It's [already suppressed on other per-site meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66774/is-it-bad-etiquette-to-have-a-0-accept-rate-on-meta-stackexchange-sites/67082#67082) but not here.  If you look at the discussion on that question in general, it seems that quite a few folks oppose displaying accept rate here on MSO as well.

Is the answer as simple as "if you don't think accept rate is relevant on MSO, just ignore it"?   Because that begs the question, who *does* think accept rate is relevant and useful information to see on questions here?

To steal from [Tobias](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146482/tobias-kienzler) on the [question mentioned above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66774/is-it-bad-etiquette-to-have-a-0-accept-rate-on-meta-stackexchange-sites):

> Meta is Meta, why should your accept rate be relevant here? I don't think so. Sometimes there is an answer explaining a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) on a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) that makes perfectly sense, or a short explanation about a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), but what *should* be the correct answer on a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)?

The best counterargument I can see, or at least explanation of why MSO would be different in this regard from the other site metas, is best stated by [Diago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132480/diago) in a comment on the question for that thread:

> MSO is still a separate beast from the rest, and the culture here has grown over time, as the site was always treated independently with it's own set of rules.

But I'm not convinced that the difference is relevant in this case.  I don't think displaying the accept rate is doing any **harm** to anyone, because I do think by and large it's ignored, but if it's just noise then why display it?

**EDIT**: since I got a fair bit of support and no official answer as to why it would be appropriate, I'm going ahead and re-tagging this as a feature request

Comment: Man, I'd totally respond to this, but... that 25% accept rate drives me away.</obligjoke>

Comment: I was **so** tempted to downvote something of your to make your rep 666, but I didn't.