# 100% accept rate on meta when not all questions have marked answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta, accept-rate

How is it possible that my MSO accept rate is 100% when I've only accepted 7 of 10 (now 11) questions? I realize the accept rate on MSO is considered to be completely than on other SE sites but is the calculation different as well?

<sub>Sorry if this is a dupe, I searched but the only question tagged with both [accept-rate](/questions/tagged/accept-rate) and [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82739/stop-displaying-the-accept-rate-on-mso) which seems to be unrelated.</sub>

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @CodyGray. I hadn't seen that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accept rate doesn't take into account questions that have no answers (since there's nothing to accept): of the questions on your profile that have no accepted answer, only [one has answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125820/149432).

Additionally, as [balpha noted in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126023/100-accept-rate-on-meta-when-not-all-questions-have-marked-answers/126024#comment340883_126024), only [questions that are older than three days count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16729/149432). Since the one question with answers is only a day old, it's not reflected in your accept rate yet.

Comment: It also ignores closed Qs doesn't it?

Comment: Is this true of all SE sites?

Comment: @M.Babcock Yes.

Comment: @BenBrocka As far as I'm aware, that's correct: closed (and deleted) questions don't count.

Comment: @MarkTrapp - Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense, but makes it's a bit confusing (probably even more so with users new to SE).

Comment: "given it was just asked yesterday and accept rate -- like most metrics -- is cached, that question is not reflected in your total yet" -- Note that (caching or not), it [wouldn't be counted before the question is three days old](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work) anyway. cc @M.Babcock

Comment: @balpha Ah thanks: learn something new every day.